# TextInputLayout - Cursor doesn't follow user typing at the end of the view

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android, android-textinputedittext

**Description:**

User starts to type a long text and when the cursor "hits" the end of the view, the EditText not scroll horizontally and all the letters typed by user after that is not shown. To see the text typed, user needs to scroll the EditText manually.

In others words, the cursor is not following the end of the text that user types as normal.

**Source code:**

On XML:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout android:id="@+id/tilEmail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/etEmail"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

On gradle

```
api 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
api 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
api 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
api "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0"
```

**Android API version:** Tested on API 28

**Device:** Pixel 3

**Update**

I found out that the problem was partially resolved when I put the attribute `android:scrollbars="vertical"` on my EditText.

"Partially resolved", because when I use this in a Activity that has `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`, the problem keep happening.

Comment: Any updates on this? @Luis

Answer (score 0):

Use a `TextInputEditText` instead of a `EditText`

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    ...>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          .../>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Automatically with `layout_height="wrap_content"` the content uses multiple lines.

[image]

Also try the latest version 1.1.0-alpha10.

Comment: But the problem is when I use `android:inputType` and `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan` (I will update my question with this information)

Answer (score 0):

Using TextInputEditText.

Try `android: scrollbars="vertical"`.
Version api `"com.google.android.material: material: 1.0.0"`

Comment: This worked solved my solution partially, because when I use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`, the problem keep happening